# How to collapse rows in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am currently pulling a `csv` list from my `database`. Then I insert that data into a `dataframe` and then insert the data into an `excel` file. Each data element is a collection of nodes where I want to collapse rows with similar top nodes.
My problem right now is the only resource I can find for doing this is `xlsxwriter`, but I need to write the data to an already existing excel file. Has anyone had success using a different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the modules `xlrd` and `xlutils` for this purpose. There's also `xlwt` if you need more advanced control over writing your Excel cells.

To write to an existing file, it would look something like this:

```
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy as xlcopy

read_book = xlrd.open_workbook('filepath/to/file.xlsx')
read_sheet = read_book.sheet_by_index(0)
write_book = xlcopy(read_book)
write_sheet = write_book.get_sheet(0)
```

You can inspect existing content in the file by reading from read_sheet by doing:

```
contents = read_sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
```

You can write new content to write_sheet by doing:

```
write_sheet.write(row_index, col_index, 'Cell contents')
```

And then finally saving it back to the original file.